# Set httpErrors existingResponse "PassThrough" programmatically ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, global-asax

I would like to set this bit of XML

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

programmatically in the Global.asax.cs instead of the Web.config.

Is it possible?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? can you elaborate properly?

Comment: We have a controller action called by an Ajax request. If it detects that some parameters are null, returns a Json result containing all the error information, with HttpStatusCode BadRequest. Then the frontent shows the Json response in a modal. The thing is that if I do not set existingResponse="PassThrough" in Web.config IIS detects the HTTP error code and overrides my Json with a IIS default error page. The problem arise because we have 50 different web.config in different servers, and it is a pain to edit them all one by one.